# Filter list based on another query result with JMESPath

Tags: python, pandas, jmespath

Having an object such as the one below:

```
{
  "pick": "a",
  "elements": [
    {"id": "a", "label": "First"},
    {"id": "b", "label": "Second"}
  ]
}
```

how can I retrieve the item in the `elements` list where `id` is equal to the value of `pick`?

I was trying something like:

```
elements[?id == pick]
```

But, apparently, the expression at the right of the comparator is evaluated relative to the object being tested against my filter expression.

How can I achieve what I want? If this is not possible out of the box, do you have any suggestion of where I should start extending JMESPath? Thank you!

Comment: **See also:** github link referring to this specific issue https://github.com/grofers/go-codon/wiki/Jmespath-extensions#3-added--to-refer-to-root-node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, *JMESPath* does not allow to reference the parent element.

To circumvent this limitation, in this simple case, you can:

- read the *pick* attribute in the first query,
- create the second query using the value just read,
- read the wanted content in the second query.

Actually, thanks to *f-strings*, two last steps can be performed in
a single instruction, so the code can be:

```
pck = jmespath.search('pick', dct)
jmespath.search(f'elements[?id == `{pck}`]', dct)
```

where *dct* is the source JSON object.

## A more complex case

If you have a more complex case (e.g. many such elements, with different *pick*
values in each case), you should use another tool.

One quite interesting option is to make use of *Pandas* package.

Assume that your source dictionary contains:

```
dct = {
  "x1": {
    "pick": "a",
    "elements": [
      {"id": "a",    "label": "First_a"},
      {"id": "b",    "label": "Second_a"},
      {"id": "c",    "label": "Third_a"}
    ]
  },
  "x2": {
    "pick": "b",
    "elements": [
      {"id": "a",    "label": "First_b"},
      {"id": "b",    "label": "Second_b"},
      {"id": "c",    "label": "Third_b"}
    ]
  }
}
```

The first thing to do is to convert *dct* into a *Pandas* DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index')
```

The result (printed in a "shortened" form) is:

```
   pick                                           elements
x1    a  [{'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_a'}, {'id': 'b', ...
x2    b  [{'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_b'}, {'id': 'b', ...
```

Description (if you have no experience in *Pandas*):

- *x1*, *x2*, ... - the index column - values taken from first level keys
  in *dct*.
- *pick* - column with (no surprise) *pick* elements,
- *elements* - column with *elements* (for now each cell contains the
  whole list).

This shape is not very much useful, so let's **explode** *elements* column:

```
df = df.explode('elements')
```

Now *df* contains:

```
   pick                          elements
x1    a   {'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_a'}
x1    a  {'id': 'b', 'label': 'Second_a'}
x1    a   {'id': 'c', 'label': 'Third_a'}
x2    b   {'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_b'}
x2    b  {'id': 'b', 'label': 'Second_b'}
x2    b   {'id': 'c', 'label': 'Third_b'}
```

This shape is closer to what we need: Each source row has been broken into
a couple of rows, each with **separate** item from the initial list.

There is one more thing to do, i.e. create a column containing *id* values,
to be later compared with *pick* column. To do it run:

```
df['id'] = df.elements.apply(lambda dct: dct['id'])
```

Now *df* contains:

```
   pick                          elements id
x1    a   {'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_a'}  a
x1    a  {'id': 'b', 'label': 'Second_a'}  b
x1    a   {'id': 'c', 'label': 'Third_a'}  c
x2    b   {'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_b'}  a
x2    b  {'id': 'b', 'label': 'Second_b'}  b
x2    b   {'id': 'c', 'label': 'Third_b'}  c
```

And to get the final result you should:

- select rows with *pick* column == *id*,
- take only *elements* column (together with key column, but this detail
  *Pandas* gives you just out of the box).

The code to do it is:

```
df.query('pick == id').elements
```

giving:

```
x1     {'id': 'a', 'label': 'First_a'}
x2    {'id': 'b', 'label': 'Second_b'}
```

In the *Pandas* parlance it is a *Series* (let's say a list with each element
"labelled" with an index.

Now you can covert it to a dictionary or whatever you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am going to accept it as the information within seems valid and useful. However, since I asked the question, I wrote a custom solution.

Comment: I read this looking for a way to explode in JMESPath. Is it impossible?